# What is $E\left[\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)-\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)\right]$ for i.i.d $X_i\sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, order-statistics

I have found the distance between the MAX and MIN of 2 random variables in a standard normal distribution.

$\text{Distance}=\mathbb{E}|X_1 - X_2|$, where $X$ has a mean of $\mu$ and a variance of $\sigma^2$.

$$X_1-X_2 \sim N(0,2σ^2) \sim {\sqrt{2}\sigma Z}\,,$$

where $Z \sim N(0,1)$.

$$\text{Distance}=\sqrt{2}\sigma\mathbb{E}|Z|$$

Then using LOTUS,

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2}\sigma\mathbb{E}(Z) &= \sqrt{2}\sigma2\int_{0}^{\infty}Z\frac{e^{-\frac{Z^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dZ
\\Distance &=\frac{\sqrt{2}\sigma2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(1)
\\Distance &=\frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align}

However, I have not been able to find the distance between the Max and MIN of 3 random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$. I believe I have the solution, but I do not know how to mathematically prove it. I believe the answer is $$\text{Distance} = \frac{3\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac{3\mathbb{E(x-\mu)}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Does anyone have a proof?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)).

Comment: I have transcribed my question using LaTeX. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help you understand my question.

Comment: I am not sure you can determine a fixed value representing the minimum value in a Normal distribution, however, the maximum value is always the mean value of course.

Comment: Your question does not entirely make sense. I think what you are asking for is not what you have written in your post.

Comment: Thank you for the above thoughts. The answer below is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Please have at look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting your posts correctly using MathJax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is the expected value of the sample range $$R=\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)-\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)=\max_{i,j}|X_i-X_j|\,,$$ where $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are i.i.d $N(0,1)$.

Since $|X_i-X_j|$ is the distance between $X_i$ and $X_j$ for all $i\ne j$, just note that

$$2R=|X_1-X_2|+|X_2-X_3|+|X_1-X_3|$$

And as $|X_1-X_2|,|X_2-X_3|$ and $|X_1-X_3|$ are all identically distributed, you have $$2\,\mathbb E(R)=3\,\mathbb E\left[|X_1-X_2|\right]=3\times\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}$$

That is, $$\mathbb E(R)=\frac{3}{\sqrt\pi}$$

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to find the expected value of R if you added a 4th random variable? R = max(X1, X2, X3, X4) - min(X1, X2, X3, X4).

Comment: [Also](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3658407/321264), $E(R)=2E[\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)]$.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com/questions/473229/expected-value-for-maximum-of-n-normal-random-variable/510580